# My apk crashes when i try to run the program after i implemented a navigation object

Tags: android, navigation

im currently struggling with my code,

Im creating a program where you can evaluate the data from a datalogger connected through a usb port.

I now wanted to also display the serial number of the device. I decided to do that with the navigation tools.

When i now press the button which should lead me to the fragment where the seriesnumber will be displayed my apk crashes and im not sure why that would happen.

This is the code i added to onCreateView:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    _binding = FragmentSleepingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.datalogger = datalogger
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

    var view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sleeping, container, false)


    // NewChanges
    bttnNavigateFragmentOne = view.findViewById(R.id.bttnNavigateToTask1)
    binding.bttnNavigateToTask1?.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.findNavController(view)
            .navigate(R.id.action_sleepingFragment_to_taskGetSeriesNumber)
    }

    //enableControls()
    return binding.root

}
```

Could it maybe be that its not working because in my nav_graph the first fragment isnt showing a preview? So there is generally some problem why i cant use the navigation tools on my already created fragments?
[image]

Thanks in advance! If you need the rest of the code from the fragment please let me know!

Comment: Crashes usually create a stack trace on logcat, so use it to identify the crash reason.

Comment: @Robert yes i know, but the problem is i have to build the APK and use it on my handy because the app only functions when i connect a datalogger. i cant use the emulator tool of android studio

Comment: Logcat is a local data buffer. Increase it's site in developer options and connect to the phone after the crash. If the logcat traffic is not too high then you will still see the crash in logcat. You can simply execute logcat on command line `adb logcat`.